# How can I cut down the complexity

Tags: java, hashmap, complexity-theory

What I give this method is to read each sentence in a large corpus in an input data and select its binary words.

Any ideas on how I should reduce the time complexity?

```
while (count < fileStream.size()) { // 1st loop

    List<String> lineArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fileStream.get(count).split("\\$+")));
    //lineArray.forEach(System.out::println);

    if (lineArray.size() > 2) {

        List<Sentence> sentences = sentenceSplitter.split(shoppingPlatform.getProductDescription());
        sentences.replaceAll(sentence -> new Sentence(sentence.toString().toLowerCase(new Locale("tr-TR"))));

        for (Sentence sentence : sentences) { // 2nd loop

            FsmParseList[] parseLists = fsm.robustMorphologicalAnalysis(sentence);
            ArrayList<FsmParse> candidateParses = morphologicalDisambiguator.disambiguate(parseLists);

            map = biGramSentences(map, map2, shortcuts, unicodes, candidateParses);

        }
        //sentences.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    count++;
}
```

The average number of lines in the file is 500000. I have 3 nested loops and O(n³) complexity.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> biGramSentences(Map<String, Integer> map, Map<String, String> map2, ArrayList<String> shortcuts, ArrayList<String> unicodes, ArrayList<FsmParse> candidateParses) {

    Set<String> keys = map2.keySet();
    for (int i = 0; i < candidateParses.size() - 1; i++) { // 3rd loop

        for (String key : keys) {

            if (candidateParses.get(i).getSurfaceForm().equals(key)) {
                ...
            }
            if (candidateParses.get(i + 1).getSurfaceForm().equals(key)) {
                ...
            }
        }

        String temp = candidateParses.get(i).getSurfaceForm() + " " + candidateParses.get(i + 1).getSurfaceForm();

        if (map.get(temp) != null) {
            map.put(temp, map.get(temp) + 1);
        } else if (map.get(temp) == null) {

            for (String unicode : unicodes) {

                if (candidateParses.get(i).getSurfaceForm().contains(unicode)) {
                   ...
                }
                if (candidateParses.get(i + 1).getSurfaceForm().contains(unicode)) {
                   ...
                }
            }

            boolean flag2 = true;
            for (String shortcut : shortcuts) {

                if (candidateParses.get(i).getSurfaceForm().equals(shortcut)
                        || candidateParses.get(i + 1).getSurfaceForm().equals(shortcut)) {

                    ...
                }
            }

            if (flag2 && (Objects.equals(candidateParses.get(i).getFinalPos(), "VERB") || Objects.equals(candidateParses.get(i + 1).getFinalPos(), "VERB")
                    || Objects.equals(candidateParses.get(i).getFinalPos(), "NUM") || Objects.equals(candidateParses.get(i + 1).getFinalPos(), "NUM")
                    || Objects.equals(candidateParses.get(i).getPos(), "PUNC") || Objects.equals(candidateParses.get(i + 1).getPos(), "PUNC"))) {

                ...
            }

            if (flag2 && (candidateParses.get(i).isPunctuation() || candidateParses.get(i + 1).isPunctuation()
                    || candidateParses.get(i).isNumber() || candidateParses.get(i + 1).isNumber())) {

                ...
            }

            if (flag2)
                map.put(temp, 1);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

The program runs extremely slow.

Comment: Your code works and you just want to improve it, so [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate. That said: don't use a linear search to check if a key exists in a map, use [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: what are binary words?